# Term by term integration of series on infinite intervals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ is given by its Taylor series such that  $\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx$ exists.

Under what conditions can we integrate term by term by replacing $f(x)$ by its Taylor series?

Comment: Under what conditions do you think $\int_0^\infty p$ is finite if $p$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @zhw only for zero polynomial?

Comment: Tonelli's theorem for sums and integrals?.

If {$f_n$} is a sequence of unsigned measurable functions, $\int \sum f_n = \sum \int f_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the radius of convergence, a power series may be integrated term-by-term.  This should be an all calculus textbooks.

I am assuming that you want to get an indefinite integral for $f$.

Example: $e^x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} x^n$, integrate term-by term to get
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\;\frac{1}{n+1} x^{n+1} = e^x-1 = \int_0^x e^t\;dt$.

(As @zhw. noted, you never get $\int_0^\infty$ this way, except for all $a_n = 0$.)